# Can Terraform choose which OS image to use according to Azure Subscription?

Tags: azure, terraform

I am using Map variable for Terraform Variables as below. When I run Terraform, I want to select prd_source_image_id if my current subscription is production, and dev_source_image_id if my current subscription is dev. Is it possible?

var.tf

```
variable "vm_template" {
  type = map(any)
  default = {
    vm1 = {
      prd_source_image_id = "prd_image"
      dev_source_image_id = "dev_image"
      }
   }
}
```

main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  for_each = var.vm_template
...(omission)
  source_image_id     = each.value.source_image_id
...(omission)
}
```

You must be able to select OS Image id based on your subscription using conditional statements or regular expressions.

Comment: It is probably possible, but how (and from where) would you get the type of subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [azurerm_client_config](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/client_config) and [lookup function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/lookup) data source :

```
    variable "vm_template" {
      type = map(any)
      default = {
        vm1 = {
          prd_source_image_id = "prd_image"
          dev_source_image_id = "dev_image"
          default_image       = "default_image"
          }
      }
    }

    variable "subscriptions_to_env" {
      type = map(string)
      default = {
        "aaa-111-555-etc" = "dev",
        "111-aaa-999-etc" = "prd"
      }
    }

    data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

    locals {
      current_env = lookup(var.subscriptions_to_env, data.azurerm_client_config.current.subscription_id, "None")
    }


    resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "vm" {
      for_each = var.vm_template
    ...(omission)
      source_image_id     = local.current_env == "dev" ? each.value.dev_source_image_id : (
                              local.current_env == "prd" ? each.value.prd_source_image_id : each.value.default_image
                              )
    ...(omission)
    }
```

Notes :
I suggest you use a default image (prd, dev or other).
The condition can be read as follow :

```
If env is dev: image dev
else if env is prd: image prd
else image default
```

Let me know if it helped you

Comment: It's working well. You're the best!

Comment: Hello ! I'm glad it helped you ! Can you mark this answer as correct / upvote so other people know this issue is cloed ? Thx